# How do I reference external objects for my template

Tags: azure-resource-manager

My ARM template needs to create DSC node configuration in Azure Automation Account which is not part of template and exists in external resource group. How do I properly reference automation account for `Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/configurations` template?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.automation/automationaccounts/configurations

Example of what I have is below

```
 {
  "name": "[reference(resourceId(parameters('AutomationaccountRGName'), 'Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/configurations', parameters('AutomationaccountName'), 'swarmhost.localhost'))]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/configurations",
  "apiVersion": "[variables('automationApiVersion')]",
  "properties": {
    "logVerbose": "false",
    "description": "Configuration for worker hosts",
    "Source": {
      "type": "uri",
      "Value": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/artisticcheese/SwarmARM/master/VMSS-Linked/swarmhost.ps1"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a reference function for that:

```
reference(resourceId('resourcegroupName', 'Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/configurations', 'automationAccountName', 'configurationName'), 'api-version')
```

reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-resource#reference

Comment: So how do I use this in my template to say add configuration resource to that account. How do I reference in which automation account it shall be created. I put example of what I have into original question

Comment: you set the type to: `Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/configurations` and you set the name to: `automationaccountName/configurationName`

Comment: Where do I use reference then? How does it know which automation account this configuration belongs to?

Comment: you are passing in the name of the automation account to use: `automationaccountname_to_use/configurationName`

Comment: So I use for "name": "[concat(reference(resourceId('resourcegroupName', 'Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/configurations', 'automationAccountName', 'configurationName'), 'api-version'), "swarmhost")]" for my configuration resource?

Comment: no, if you are asking for that, for the name you use this pattern: your parent resource name + / + resource you are creating name. in your case its: `concat(parameters('AutomationaccountRGName'), '/swarmhost.localhost')). in case your automation account is in another resource group you need to create that resource using a child\nested deployment into that specific resource group.

Comment: Here is what I have now and it does not work. Automation account itself is not created in template at all. All I want to do is to add configuration to account which I need to reference via parameter passed of resource group and account name. Below complaining of wrong type https://pastebin.com/30wXuqMP